# How to Upload files to AWS from Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, ubuntu-14.04

I'm doing a project and have to access AWS in order to maintain files and other stuffs.

I've connected to my AWS instance and now want to upload some files from my own computer system. There I can use only terminal.

My question is that how can I upload those files or directories to my AWS instance from my computer or any other method like first I upload those files to any third party server like github and then download or clone it from there?

Please suggest me an easy way of uploading from my own computer or present me with an alternative.

Comment: Why can't you 'scp' the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing your code to Github and pulling from Github when you ssh into an AWS instance is a good way to deploy.

https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've used bitbucket. Thanks for answering